# How to assign non consant value to 2D array size in c++?

Tags: arrays, dynamic-allocation

I need to make a 2D array but the problem is that I need to use string size as the size of array. So far I did this but I keep getting error "expression must have a constant value". My program needs to read a string from txt file,and then use string length/size for 2D array size. For instance: I wrote "hello" in txt file and its length is 5. Now I need to use this length and store it as variable N and use it as dimension for 2D array.
How to do it guys for this example?

```
 int main()
{
    string s;
    ifstream myfile("palindrome.txt", ios::out);        //reading my txt file

    if (myfile.is_open()) 
        {
            getline(myfile, s); //storing string in variable s
        }
    myfile.close();

    int l = s.size(); //reading size of string and storing to variable l
    const int N = l; 
    int* R= new int[2][N + 1];
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Error C2540 non-constant expression as array bound

Comment: If you want to allocate memory for an array of array with one new, the second size must be constant. In Your case I think you should declare an array (or a vector) of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
const int N = l;

int** R = new int*[2];

for(int i = 0; (i < 2); i++)
{
    R[i] = new int[N + 1];   
}
```

Loop through twice as this is what you set the rows to be in the first initialization. You need to allocate its memory on the heap, but remember, you will need to free this memory once you're done. This can be done through:

```
for(int i = 0; (i < 2); i++)
   delete[] R[i];
delete[] R;
```